# Does Google Cloud Loadbalancer support http2 for grpc?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grpc

Is it possible to put multiple grpc services behind a google Cloud Loadbalancer (specifically one running inside container engine) to allow load balancing of multiple grpc backend services?

Comment: Why can't we put mutiple grpc services behind load balancer. Its upon user to configure balancer & support both http2 & grpc

Comment: Grpc uses http2 therefore the Loadbalancer must support http2 (I believe Google lb only does http2-> http1 translation, hence the question)

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported (see: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#HTTP2-limitations).

Your other option is to use an L4 LoadBalancer.